# Absolute value for width of shape in svg for d3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

The code for my scaling function is:

```
 var innerWidth = 117;
 var innerHeight = 14;
 // create a scaling function
 var max = .8;
 var min = -.7;
 var wScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, max])
 .range([0, innerWidth]);
```

The code for creating rectangle is

```
 var sel = selection.selectAll("svg")
 .selectAll("rect")
 .transition().duration(500)
 .attr("width", function(d) { return wScale(Math.abs(d))});
```

However this doesn't seem to work and for negative values of d no rectangle is formed when I want the width of the rectangle to be according to the absolute value of d.

**EDIT**

My question is with reference to this app generously provided [here](https://thomassiegmund.shinyapps.io/interaction/).and is related to the horizontal blue bars. Being naïve with JS, after a bit of exploring I have identified the chunk of code in the app which is creating the horizontal blue bars. However Instead of the same bars I want it slightly differently [image]

This is the code creating the plot.

```
 col_3 = JS('function makeGraph(selection){

        // find out which table and column
        var regex = /(col_\\d+)/;
        var col = regex.exec(this[0][0].className)[0];
        var regex = /tbl_(\\S+)/;
        var tbl = regex.exec(this[0][0].className)[1];
        var innerWidth = 117;
        var innerHeight = 14;
        
        // create a scaling function
        var max = colMax(tbl, col);
        var min = colMin(tbl, col);
        var wScale = d3.scale.linear()
                       .domain([0, max])
                       .range([0, innerWidth]);

        // text formatting function
        var textformat = d3.format(".1f");

        // column has been initialized before, update function
        if(tbl + "_" + col + "_init" in window) {
            var sel = selection.selectAll("svg")
                     .selectAll("rect")
                     .transition().duration(500)
                     .attr("width", function(d) { return wScale(d.value)});
            var txt = selection
                        .selectAll("text")
                        .text(function(d) { return textformat(d.value); });
           return(null);
        }
        
        // can remove padding here, but still can't position text and box independently
        this.style("padding", "5px 5px 5px 5px");

        // remove text. will be added back later
        selection.text(null);

        var svg = selection.append("svg")
              .style("position",  "absolute")
              .attr("width", innerWidth)
              .attr("height", innerHeight);

        var box = svg.append("rect")
                     .style("fill", "lightblue")
                     .attr("stroke","none")
                     .attr("height", innerHeight)
                     .attr("width", min)
                     .transition().duration(500)
                     .attr("width", function(d) { return wScale(d.value); });

        // format number and add text back
        var textdiv = selection.append("div");
                          textdiv.style("position",  "relative")
                                 .attr("align", "right");

        textdiv.append("text")
                 .text(function(d) { return textformat(d.value); });
        window[tbl + "_" + col + "_init"] = true;
      }')
```

Comment: Can you please give more information about your colMax(tbl, col)?  What does it do?

Comment: colMax(tbl, col) was basically a function which returned the max value of column "col" in d3tablefilter "tbl". To remove confusion I have replaced them with values

Comment: Aah, and i also think that you need to feed your graph some data! after you selection, you still need to say to D3 using the data() function what data you are going to use

Comment: Ok. However I was wondering why wScale(Math.abs(d)) is not working?. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: Yes, the syntax of the scale function is correct. I tried something silly in plunker to make sure. Could you post / plunker the full code please?

Comment: I have added my full intent behind this question

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of missing element in your code. The selection is not defined. You have to call the data function with data. There must be an enter section with append.

I created a fiddle with some made up parameter from your code.
It works more or less.

```
var data =[1];

 var sel = d3.select("svg")
   .selectAll("rect")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
     .attr("width",10)
     .attr("height",40)
     .attr('x', 1.5)
     .attr('y', 1.5)
     .transition().duration(500)
       .attr("width", function(d) { return wScale(Math.abs(d))});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acerola/symcuccm/